# Shopware 400 Status Error "This value is too long. It should have 255 character or less." When I Try Updating Database Table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

When I try posting into Shopware 6 database table, I get a `400` status response with additional details **This value is too long. It should have 255 character or less.**

The data field **description** which I am trying to update accepts **longtext**.

My database table is **clu_product_text** and the table column I want to update is **description** and accepts **longtext**. The **400** status Error message is "**This value is too long. It should have 255 character or less.**"

Below is my code:

```js
const { Component} = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;


Component.register('clu-administration-page', {

   template,

   inject: [
    'repositoryFactory',
    'syncService'
    
    ],

   metaInfo() {
      return {
          title: this.$createTitle()
      };
    },


  data: function () {

    return {

        description: "For writers, a random sentence can help them get their creative juices flowing. Since the topic of the sentence is completely unknown, it forces the writer to be creative when the sentence appears. There are a number of different ways a writer can use the random sentence for creativity. The most common way to use the sentence is to begin a story. Another option is to include it somewhere in the story. A much more difficult challenge is to use it to end a story. In any of these cases, it forces the writer to think creatively since they have no idea what sentence will appear from the tool.",
        id: "34eh9037492h2781",
        isLoading: true

    }

   },

   computed: {

        cluProductTextRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('clu_product_text');
        },

        
    
   },


   methods: {


        updateCluProductText(){

            this.cluProductTextRepository
                .get(this.id, Shopware.Context.api)
                .then((update) => {
                    update.description = this.description;
                    this.cluProductTextRepository.save(update, Shopware.Context.api);
                });

        }



   },

   

   created() {

       
        this.updateCluProductText();
       
       
    
   } 

   
    
  
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringField` on the definition of your custom entitiy has a third parameter `maxLength` which by default is set to 255. For longer text you should use the `LongTextField` instead.

So I assume your entity definition looks something like this:

```php
public function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
   return new FieldCollection([
      ... your other fields
      new StringField('clu_product_text', 'cluProductText'),
   ]);
}
```

Instead you should use the `LongTextField`:

```php
public function defineFields(): FieldCollection
{
   return new FieldCollection([
      ... your other fields
      new LongTextField('clu_product_text', 'cluProductText'),
   ]);
}
```